# Mysql if-clause sequence

Tags: mysql, case-when

I have a table of transactions like so. 4 fields:
time   id   type   money

One of the types has 3 different subtypes (21,22,23), from which I want to create additional types based on the ids and then calculate money per date and type. I am doing it like so.

```
select date(time), sum(money),
case
when type=2 and id<100 then type=21
when type=2 and id between 100 and 499 then type=22
when type=2 and id>=500 then type=23
when type<>2 then type
end as type
from transactionsTable
where type in (1,2,3,4,21,22,23) and date(time)>='2014-11-01' group by 1,3
```

One of the weird results is that I get a type=0, which I filtered out within where clause.
The second weird thing is that I don't get newly created types 21,22,23 whatsoever!

Could anyone point me into the right direction please?

Comment: I commented to John. He pointed out exactly the core mistakes. Nevertheless, I don't quite comprehend the "type" mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot reference a type like that in a where or set a type without some sort of insert. what you can do though is use the result from this query to write a query to return what you want.

```
SELECT  DATE(time), SUM(money),
        CASE
            WHEN type=2 AND id<100 
                THEN 21
            WHEN type=2 AND id BETWEEN 100 AND 499 
                THEN 22
            WHEN type=2 AND id>=500 
                THEN 23
            WHEN type<>2 
                THEN type
        END AS type
FROM transactionsTable
GROUP BY 1,3
HAVING type IN (1,2,3,4,21,22,23) AND DATE(time)>='2014-11-01'
```

[**SIMPLIFIED FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c7fa7/1)

note: having clause re evaluates the result set so you can reference type in the having to include the results from your query

Comment: Many thanks John! it works just fine the way you wrote it. Just one question. What is the difference between "then 21" and "then type=21". It's not a syntax error, otherwise it would've thrown an error. Nevertheless, the results were completely screwed.

Comment: @user3892041 type=21 isn't doing an assignment. so what it is doing is a boolean comparison which will always be 0 or false since type is 2. when putting in the number its saying that column for that row has the value 21.. which when you alias it as type `END AS type` it returns a column with the 'type' being 21 so you can use it in another query or with a HAVING clause :)

Comment: @user3892041 a boolean comparison as in type is equal to 2. and its saying is type = 21. which is false so it returns a 0. I gave you a +1 id appreciate the same from you :) thanks

Comment: You mean some other question of yours or the comment? :) I am a novice on stackoverflow so I am still getting used to the rules.

Comment: @user3892041 a +1 on the answer :) because that gives reputation. the +1 on a comment means its a good and noteworthy comment (a helpful one) and it will display it over other comments